# How can I apply Conway's game of life tick correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, conways-game-of-life

In Conway's game of life algorithm, it reads:

> The first generation is created by applying the above rules simultaneously to every cell in the seed; births and deaths occur simultaneously, and the discrete moment at which this happens is sometimes called a tick.

How can I apply a mapping function to each element of an array simultaneously? Is this really what it's asking? My code appears to work, but once life begins it behaves erratically and in absolutely no situation it dies completely, it only expands until it takes up my whole width/height. So there's obviously something wrong in my implementation, and from my perspective I could only link it to my misconception of what a tick actually means and how it is applied.

Here is my implementation:

```
conways(xRow: number, yRow: number) {

    // Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if by underpopulation.
    // Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
    // Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overpopulation.
    // Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

    let matrix = [], tracker = [];
    const tileSize = new Dimension(Math.floor(this.dimensions.width / xRow), Math.floor(this.dimensions.height / yRow));

    for (let i = 0; i < xRow; i++) matrix[i] = new Array(yRow);

    for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) === 1) {
                matrix[i][j] = new GameObject(Model.RECTANGLE, new Point(i * tileSize.width, j * tileSize.height), new Dimension(tileSize.width, tileSize.height), "black");
                matrix[i][j].addProperty("alive", true);
            }
            else {
                matrix[i][j] = new GameObject(Model.RECTANGLE, new Point(i * tileSize.width, j * tileSize.height), new Dimension(tileSize.width, tileSize.height), "white");
                matrix[i][j].addProperty("alive", false);
            }
            this.render.requestStage(matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    let isAlive = (position: Point, world: GameObject[][]) => {
        let neighboursCount = 0;

        const cellStatus = world[position.x][position.y].props["alive"];

        if (world[position.x + 1] && world[position.x + 1][position.y] && 
            world[position.x + 1][position.y].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

        if (world[position.x - 1] && world[position.x - 1][position.y] && 
            world[position.x - 1][position.y].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

        if (world[position.x] && world[position.x][position.y + 1] && 
            world[position.x][position.y + 1].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

        if (world[position.x] && world[position.x][position.y - 1] &&
            world[position.x][position.y - 1].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

        if (world[position.x - 1] && world[position.x - 1][position.y + 1] && 
            world[position.x - 1][position.y + 1].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

        if (world[position.x + 1] && world[position.x + 1][position.y + 1] && 
            world[position.x + 1][position.y + 1].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

        if (world[position.x - 1] && world[position.x - 1][position.y - 1] && 
            world[position.x - 1][position.y - 1].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

        if (world[position.x + 1] && world[position.x + 1][position.y - 1] && 
            world[position.x + 1][position.y - 1].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

        if (cellStatus) {
            if (neighboursCount < 2) return false;
            if (neighboursCount === 2 || neighboursCount === 3) return true;
            if (neighboursCount > 3) return false;
        }
        else if (!cellStatus && neighboursCount === 3) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    setInterval(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                let alive = isAlive(new Point(i, j), matrix);
                if (alive) {
                    matrix[i][j].color = "black";
                    matrix[i][j].props["alive"] = true;
                }
                else {
                    matrix[i][j].props["alive"] = false;
                    matrix[i][j].color = "white";
                }
            }
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Please don't mind the custom constructors and functions since this is my take on a 'graphic library' that actually only links to the Canvas API and ImageData. What I'm doing is basically:

-Creating a matrix of size w/h.

-When iterating over it, theres a 1/10 of a chance of a cell to be alive. (Coming up with a random seed because I haven't added input yet)

-Render it all on the screen.

-Every 10ms I apply Conway's rules to each cell iteratively, and I change their color/state accordingly.

Comment: You need to keep the previous generation unmodified, and have a new table for the next generation.

Comment: Could use expand it further if you can, please? I mean, I could store the 'previous' state of the cells in a table and the next in another. But I don't understand why I should do it.

Comment: This is a classic "buffer" situation: you have _two_ boards, of equal size, and your tick takes one board, and fills in "the other board" by applying Conway's rules. Once you've finished processing, you flip which board is the active board and draw that.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhh, pretty much how a buffer actually works, right? I remember learning it when I was reading about SDL double buffering. It clearly didn't occur to me. I'll give it a try, thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's crystal clear now. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Using the buffer strategy suggested by Mike and hyde I got it working. Here are the changes for the interested:

```
conways(xRow: number, yRow: number) {

        // Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if by underpopulation.
        // Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
        // Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overpopulation.
        // Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

        let matrix = [], bufferMatrix = [];
        const tileSize = new Dimension(Math.floor(this.dimensions.width / xRow), Math.floor(this.dimensions.height / yRow));

        for (let i = 0; i < xRow; i++) matrix[i] = new Array(yRow);
        for (let i = 0; i < xRow; i++) bufferMatrix[i] = new Array(yRow);

        for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) === 1) {
                    matrix[i][j] = new GameObject(Model.RECTANGLE, new Point(i * tileSize.width, j * tileSize.height), new Dimension(tileSize.width, tileSize.height), "black");
                    matrix[i][j].addProperty("alive", true);
                    bufferMatrix[i][j] = new GameObject(Model.RECTANGLE, new Point(i * tileSize.width, j * tileSize.height), new Dimension(tileSize.width, tileSize.height), "black");
                    bufferMatrix[i][j].addProperty("alive", true);
                }
                else {
                    matrix[i][j] = new GameObject(Model.RECTANGLE, new Point(i * tileSize.width, j * tileSize.height), new Dimension(tileSize.width, tileSize.height), "white");
                    matrix[i][j].addProperty("alive", false);
                    bufferMatrix[i][j] = new GameObject(Model.RECTANGLE, new Point(i * tileSize.width, j * tileSize.height), new Dimension(tileSize.width, tileSize.height), "white");
                    bufferMatrix[i][j].addProperty("alive", false);
                }
                this.render.requestStage(matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }

        let isAlive = (position: Point, world: GameObject[][]) => {
            let neighboursCount = 0;

            const cellStatus = world[position.x][position.y].props["alive"];

            if (world[position.x + 1] && world[position.x + 1][position.y] && 
                world[position.x + 1][position.y].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

            if (world[position.x - 1] && world[position.x - 1][position.y] && 
                world[position.x - 1][position.y].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

            if (world[position.x] && world[position.x][position.y + 1] && 
                world[position.x][position.y + 1].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

            if (world[position.x] && world[position.x][position.y - 1] &&
                world[position.x][position.y - 1].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

            if (world[position.x - 1] && world[position.x - 1][position.y + 1] && 
                world[position.x - 1][position.y + 1].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

            if (world[position.x + 1] && world[position.x + 1][position.y + 1] && 
                world[position.x + 1][position.y + 1].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

            if (world[position.x - 1] && world[position.x - 1][position.y - 1] && 
                world[position.x - 1][position.y - 1].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

            if (world[position.x + 1] && world[position.x + 1][position.y - 1] && 
                world[position.x + 1][position.y - 1].props["alive"]) neighboursCount++;

            if (cellStatus) {
                if (neighboursCount < 2) return false;
                if (neighboursCount === 2 || neighboursCount === 3) return true;
                if (neighboursCount > 3) return false;
            }
            else if (!cellStatus && neighboursCount === 3) return true;
            else return false;
        }

        setInterval(() => {
            this.render.clearStage();
            for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                    let alive = isAlive(new Point(i, j), matrix);
                    if (alive) {
                        bufferMatrix[i][j].color = "black";
                        bufferMatrix[i][j].props["alive"] = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        bufferMatrix[i][j].props["alive"] = false;
                        bufferMatrix[i][j].color = "white";
                    }
                    this.render.requestStage(matrix[i][j]);
                }
            }
            // Matching properties from bufferedMatrix and matrix without losing reference.
            for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                    matrix[i][j].color = bufferMatrix[i][j].color;
                    matrix[i][j].props["alive"] = bufferMatrix[i][j].props["alive"];
                }
            }
        }, 100);
    }
```